# Find the inverse of $ 5+4i $ in $ \mathbb{Z}[i] / 7 \mathbb{Z}[i] $.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> (1) Find the inverse of $ 5+4i $ in $ \mathbb{Z}[i] / 7 \mathbb{Z}[i] $.
>
> (2) Check whether $ 2+6 \sqrt 5$ is invertible in $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 5] / 11 \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 5] $.

**Answer:**

(1) Let $ a+bi $ is the inverse of $ 5+4i $. Then $ (a+bi)(5+4i)=1 $ .

Or, $ (5a-4b)+i(4a+5b)=1 \in \mathbb{Z}[i] / 7 \mathbb{Z}[i] $.

Or, $ 5a-4b \equiv 1 \ (mod \ 7) \ \ and \ \ 4a+5b \equiv 0 \ (mod \ 7) $

Solving we get $ a \equiv -5 \ (mod \ 7) \ \ and \ \ b \equiv 4 \ (mod \ 7) $.

So the inverse of $ 5+4i \ \ $ is $ \ \ -5+4i $.

**Am I true? Also any help for the next part.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Here is another solution:

$(5+4i)(5-4i) = 41 \equiv -1 \bmod 7$.
Hence, $-(5-4i)$ is the inverse of $5+4i$ mod $7$.

(2) Assuming you mean $2+6 \sqrt 5$, then

$(2+6 \sqrt 5)(2-6 \sqrt 5) = -176 \equiv 0 \bmod 11$. Hence, $2+6 \sqrt 5$ is not invertible mod $11$.